# Oddity: Whitespace at top of HTML

Tags: css, html

I've got a problem with a site I'm working on where there is whitespace appearing at the top of the file (and 1 px to the right) for apparently no reason. I've added `margin: 0; padding:0;` to both `<body>` and `<html>` to no avail.

When I've inspected it in Chrome DevTools, I can't seem to find any elements that are causing it. If I remember correctly it also appears when there is no CSS present. HTML and CSS are below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="sec-1">
            <header>
                <nav class="flo-l">
                    <a href="#services" class="ed">Services</a>
                    <a href="#contact" class="ed">Email</a>             </nav>
                <h1 class="lava">Hillside Insurance Agency</h1> 
                    <nav class="flo-r">
                    <a href="#contact" class="ed">Phone</a>
                    <a href="#about" class="ed">About</a>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div>
                <h1 class="fv">Protection, Integrity, Service.</h1>
                <h2>We have the protection you need. <br>
                    Call or email us today.</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sec-2">
            <nav>
                <a href="#services" class="active ed">Services</a>
                <a href="#contact" class="ed">Email</a>
                <a href="#contact" class="ed">Phone</a>
                <a href="#about" class="ed">About</a>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <section class="flo-l">
                    <h3 class="fv">Insurance we offer</h3>
                    <h4>Business coverage in New York and Georgia.</h4>
                </section>
                <section class="flo-r vertLin">
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Martial Arts Centers</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Museums</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i> Child Care Centers</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Libraries</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> Fairs and Fairgrounds</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Adult Care Centers</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i> Religious Organizations</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Yoga Studios</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Dance Studios</p>
                    <p class="fv"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Gymnasiums</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="sec-3">
            <div id="contact">
                <div class="flo-l">
                    <h3 class="fv">Email</h3>
                    <p>comprehensive contact</p>
                    <a href="mailto:hillshireagency@yahoo.com" class="contact">hillshireagency@yahoo.com</a>
                    <p>Get an insurance quote</p>
                    <p>Get in touch via the internet and get a quote on insurance for your business</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flo-r">
                    <h3 class="fv">Phone</h3>
                    <p>personal contact</p>
                    <h3>315-747-4544</h3>
                    <p>Get an insurance quote</p>
                    <p>Get in touch via the internet and get a quote on insurance for your business</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flo-bottom"><h3>Let us protect you, so you can focus on your business.</h3></div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
    /* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 Boilerplate styles - h5bp.com (generated via initializr.com)
   ========================================================================== */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}




/***************
    Webfonts: 
***************/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'edmondsans';
    src: url('edmondsans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('edmondsans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('edmondsans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('edmondsans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('edmondsans-regular-webfont.svg#edmondsans') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'fairview';
    src: url('fairview_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fairview_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fairview_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fairview_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fairview_regular-webfont.svg#fairview') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lavanderia';
    src: url('lavanderia_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('lavanderia_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('lavanderia_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('lavanderia_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('lavanderia_regular-webfont.svg#lavanderia') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
/***************
    Content:
***************/

/* Floats: */

.flo-l {
    float: left;
}

.flo-r {
    float: right;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Font settings: */

.ed {
    font-family: "edmondsans", sans-serif
}

.fv {
    font-family: "fairview", sans-serif
}

.lava {
    font-family: "lavanderia", sans-serif
}
/* Sections: */

#sec-1 {
min-width:960px;
height: 438px;
background-image: url(../images/headbg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #EEE;
background-size: cover;
}

#sec-2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 419px;
}

#sec-3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 418px;
    background: #375e00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #375e00 0%, #0f3201 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#375e00), color-stop(100%,#0f3201)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #375e00 0%,#0f3201 100%); /*  Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #375e00 0%,#0f3201 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #375e00 0%,#0f3201 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #375e00 0%,#0f3201 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#375e00', endColorstr='#0f3201',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background-image: url(../images/stacked_circles.png) repeat;

}

/* Sub-sections: */

#contact {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;

    /* Background Gradient: */
    background: #d7d7d7; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%, #f0f0f0 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d7d7d7), color-stop(100%,#f0f0f0)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%,#f0f0f0 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%,#f0f0f0 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7d7d7 0%,#f0f0f0 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d7d7d7 0%,#f0f0f0 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d7d7d7', endColorstr='#f0f0f0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    /* Box-shadow: */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset  5px px  rgba(255, 255, 190, 75);
    box-shadow: inset  5px px  rgba(255, 255, 190, 75);

    /* Border: */
    border: 1px solid black
}

/* Other: */
.vertLin {
    border-left: thick solid #000;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Media Queries
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {

}

@media print,
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {

}

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
     */

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before.  I honestly am looking for a better fix, but it annoys me so much I just end up using absolute positioning on html (or body maybe) and set the top to 0.  I know this is a quick fix and probably not what you're looking for.

So you can try the following:

```
html, body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

That should at least fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A friend contacted me and said it's WebKit's fault. If you inspect the H1 in the header, it adds I believe 0.83em to the h1 with

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) :-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1
```

It does the same with H2 and other elements as well. I have no idea why they would do this. A supposition on their part? Seems dumb to me, but I'm not an expert. Anyway, here's the fix for the h1s:

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) :-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
        margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a CSS Reset sheet? I find it removes most of these frustrations and gives you a blank state to work from.

I tend to use:

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem when I was floating elements and not using clearfix properly. Check if you use clearfix for every element that contains children element with float: left or float: right property.

for example:

```
<header class="clearfix">
   <nav class="flo-l">
      <a href="#services" class="ed">Services</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="ed">Email</a>
   </nav>
   <h1 class="lava">Hillside Insurance Agency</h1> 
   <nav class="flo-r">
      <a href="#contact" class="ed">Phone</a>
      <a href="#about" class="ed">About</a>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Check all element in whole document. I works for me.